# Request body validation with http Mux

Tags: go, mux

I am trying to build an API using Go and Mux. I am trying to validate the incoming requests. I tried using tags on Struct and validated it using [Go Validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator).

This is my Struct

```
type Address struct {
    Street string `validate:"required"`
    City   string `validate:"required"`
    Phone  string `validate:"required"`
}
```

My issue is

- There is a `POST` endpoint where all the fields would be passed and the validation would not fail. However there is another `PATCH` endpoint where not all fields of `Address` struct would be passed and hence the validation is failing.

eg. API might receive

```
{
  "Street": "Dummy"
}
```

What is the best way to validate both `POST` and `PATCH` request in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Change my answer**

I've been tested on your case and found the solution, you must use [struct level validation](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/_examples/struct-level/main.go). Here is the my function on your case:

```
func PostRequestValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {

    address := sl.Current().Interface().(Address)

    jsonMarshal, _ := json.Marshal(address)
    var m map[string]interface{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(jsonMarshal, &m)
    for key, val := range m {
        if len(fmt.Sprintf("%s", val)) == 0 {
            sl.ReportError(val, key, key, "post", "")
        }
    }
}

func PutRequestValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {

    address := sl.Current().Interface().(Address)

    isValid := false

    jsonMarshal, _ := json.Marshal(address)
    var m map[string]interface{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(jsonMarshal, &m)
    for _, val := range m {
        if len(fmt.Sprintf("%s", val)) > 0 {
            isValid = true
        }
    }

    if !isValid {
        sl.ReportError(address, "address", "Adress", "put", "")
    }
}
```

You just have to register on each validation request

```
    // ON POST REQUEST
    validate = validator.New()
    validate.RegisterTagNameFunc(func(fld reflect.StructField) string {
        name := strings.SplitN(fld.Tag.Get("json"), ",", 2)[0]
        if name == "-" {
            return ""
        }
        return name
    })
    validate.RegisterStructValidation(PostRequestValidation, Address{})
```

```
    // ON PUT REQUEST
    validate = validator.New()
    validate.RegisterTagNameFunc(func(fld reflect.StructField) string {
        name := strings.SplitN(fld.Tag.Get("json"), ",", 2)[0]
        if name == "-" {
            return ""
        }
        return name
    })
    validate.RegisterStructValidation(PutRequestValidation, Address{})
```

You may copy from my [source code](https://gist.github.com/fahimbagar/f16b38c6a2ab9ef134cf73b3391965a9) for more detailed source code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But using one of the above would invalidate POST request since in POST we would require all the fields. Any suggestions here ?

Comment: aha, so if you need multiple condition like that, you may use Or operator. Take as example     Street string `validate:"required|required_without_all"`  . Replace the validation for each fields. I'll update my answer based on this comment. You should update your question based on the comment.

Comment: I have updated the question. Made it clear now :) this still is not working - the or condition does not evaluate properly. Say for `PATCH` I don't require `City` but for `POST` `City` is required. Having the or conditon allows the `POST` payload to be validated even if `City` is not provided.

Comment: hi, I hope you can modify my code based on what your needs, sorry for my previous answer, it's misleading. Don't forget to mark this question as solved if it's answered yours.

Answer (score 1):

In the PATCH endpoint use a different type with different (if any) validation tags. Convert to Address afterward:

```
// Same underlying type as Address, but no validation tags
var x struct {
    Street string
    City   string
    Phone  string
}

// Decode request into x, then:

addr := Address(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case if we add a new field then we would have to change it in all the types that were created right.

Comment: Yes. The compiler will make sure you don't forget one.

Answer (score 0):

Found this library - [govalidator](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/govalidator). This allows to create rules for each request based on the requirement. For POST request, create a set of rules with all the fields as mandatory. For PATCH request, create rules with all fields as optional.